# Should an acronym that is ending a sentence have a period?

Tags: grammar, periods

As an example, I have written this sentence: "People are trying to stop them from doing this in other countries, such as the U.N."
Should this have a period at the end?

Comment: Do acronyms have periods at all to begin with?

Comment: Not related to the punctuation issue, but to your sentence:  as written, it is implicitly stating that "the U.N." is a country, but the U.N. is definitely not a country.

Comment: (Per the answers at the suggested duplicate, never 'double up' on the punctuation:  The period that is part of "U.N." also serves as the end-of-sentence mark.)

Comment: No.  It may be logical, but it looks funny.

Comment: @Hellion That question is about abbreviations, not acronyms. So it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Well, thanks for all the information. At least I know now.